# How to append git short hash into Octopus release from TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

Using an `OctopusDeploy: Create Release` runner in TeamCity, I can create a release with the `build.number` fairly easily.

I'd like to add a suffix of the git commit short hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I solved it - scraped from various internet sources

In my **CI Build**, I added

1. A parameter named `system.GitHashShort`
2. Created a Powershell runner which executes this

   `$hash = "%build.vcs.number%"
   $shortHash = $hash.substring(0,7)
   Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='system.GitHashShort' value='$shortHash']"`

In my **Deploy** build configuration which is a snapshot dependency on *CI Build*

1. For the `OctopusDeploy: Create Release` runner, set the *release number* to be 

   `%build.number%-%dep.MyAwesomeApp.system.GitHashShort%`

This then gives builds of a format like 8.3.422.34-deadbee